# Is there a git command to add a file to .git/info/exclude

Tags: git, command-line

The default IDE for a repo I've been working with is QtCreator, but I work a lot in Visual Studio, and so I managed to build it from there.

The only problem is that VS specific files get created by the IDE, and I don't want to bother everyone by adding these files to .gitignore. That's why I use .git/info/exclude a lot. (happens with other projects too)

Is there a way to add a file to .git/info/exclude from the command line?
Something like `git exclude myfile.cpp`

Comment: `echo myfile.cpp >>.git/info/exclude`.

Comment: @jthill thanks. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jthill pointed out in the comments, the simplest way is not to use git at all:

`echo myfile.cpp >>.git/info/exclude`

Does exactly what was needed.

For simplifying the process, I typed `git config --global -e` and added it as an alias:

`exclude = "!f() { echo \"$1\" >> \".git/info/exclude\"}; f"`

Answer (score 2):

Your own toolchain's detritus belongs in your own per-user ignores, `~/.config/git/ignore` or wherever your `core.excludesfile` says. That way you only have to add the main patterns once.

But for one-offs, the usual way of adding a line to a text file is `echo` appending to that file, e.g.  `echo myfile.cpp >>.git/info/exclude`.

Getting used to having a first-class toolkit available for *every* environment seems to befuddle Windows users, just as Windows users wanting every tool to re-implement the entire Unix toolkit (one piece at a time) befuddles Unix users. Why on earth should Git implement all of the basic text-processing tools when you've already got them? coreutils, grep, sed, awk are there for everyone.

Comment: It is good to know, but it doesn't answer the question. Is there a git command to add files to .git/info/exclude?

Comment: See the edit. There's already a way to do that. Every command add a new way to spell doing exactly the same thing would be a colossal waste of effort, you'd wind up with every command re-implementing the whole Unix toolkit. Which everybody who wants it already has. You're asking for a new way to do what one of the simplest tools already does.

Comment: You are right, but git does include this kind of function. Think of `git alias`